# How can I import data from a child URL?

Tags: vba, excel

I thought I figured this out over the weekend, but it actually doesn't work the way I thought it would.  I have a confidential corporate SharePoint site that I work with.  I can't post the link here, or any specific data, but the concept below will illustrate the point fine.

I have a parent URL that I want to import data from.  Let's say this is the parent URL.

http://www.sharenet.co.za/v3/q_sharelookup.php

From there, I want to import data from a specific link.  Let's say this is the link:  'Building & Construction Materials'

I think the best way to do this is some kind of InStr() function and search for the string.  Then, if found, click the link and open the child URL.  When the child URL opens, it looks something like this:

http://www.sharenet.co.za/v3/sharesfound.php?ssector=2353&exch=JSE&bookmark=Building%20&%20Construction%20Materials&scheme=default

I can't tell what the sector numbers will be ahead of time, so I can't use a specific URL.  I need to reference it as the parent and child, or maybe IE1 and IE2.  I want to import all data from the child URL, which in this example, looks like this.

```
Name    Full Name   Code    Sector
 BUILDMX     BUILDMAX LIMITED       BDM     2353
 KAYDAV      KAYDAV GROUP LTD       KDV     2353
 AFRIMAT     AFRIMAT LTD    AFT     2353
 Trellidor       Trellidor Hldgs Ltd    TRL     2353
 MASONITE    MASONITE (AFRICA) LIMITED      MAS     2353
 DAWN    DISTRIBUTION AND WAREHOUSING NETWORK LIMITED       DAW     2353
 MAZOR       MAZOR GROUP LTD    MZR     2353
 PPC     PPC LIMITED    PPC     2353
 PPCN    PPC Limited NPL    PPCN    2353
```

Just to demonstrate how I tried to solve this, I tried the script below.

```
Sub ListLinks()

'Set a reference to microsoft Internet Controls
Dim IeApp As InternetExplorer
Dim sURL As String
Dim IeDoc As Object
Dim i As Long

Set IeApp = New InternetExplorer

IeApp.Visible = True

sURL = "http://www.sharenet.co.za/v3/q_sharelookup.php"

IeApp.Navigate sURL

Do
Loop Until IeApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Set IeDoc = IeApp.Document

For i = 0 To IeDoc.Links.Length - 1
    Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = IeDoc.Links(i).href
Next i

Set IeApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

I thought it would work fine, to list all URLs, and then loop through each to import data, but the problem on my SharePoint site is that the href doesn't appear to have any relevance to the name of the hyperlink.

[image]

In the picture above you can see 'Building & Construction Materials' in the TD element.  If I can reference that in the 1st browser, and click the correct link to open a 2nd browser, and then reference that 2nd browser and scrape all TD elements from that, everything should work fine.  Does anyone here know how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Good try on the code, got it pretty close- the one area that needs some fixing is when you try and get the list of items and loop it. You had the right idea on how it would work, but the HTML element syntaxes a little off so looks like just need some more experience using HTML objects... see sample code below:

```
Public Sub sampleCode()
Dim URL As String
Dim XMLHTTP As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim HTMLDoc_Main As HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLDoc_Secondary As HTMLDocument
Dim targetTable As HTMLObjectElement
Dim links As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim linkCounter As Long

Dim searchText As String

URL = "http://www.sharenet.co.za/v3/q_sharelookup.php"
searchText = "Building & Construction Materials"

Set XMLHTTP = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Set HTMLDoc_Main = New HTMLDocument
With XMLHTTP
    .Open "GET", URL, False
    .send
    While .readyState <> 4: Wend
    HTMLDoc_Main.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With

Set targetTable = HTMLDoc_Main.getElementsByClassName("dataTable")(0)
Set links = targetTable.getElementsByTagName("a")
For linkCounter = 0 To links.Length - 1
    With links(linkCounter)
        If InStr(1, .innerText, searchText) > 0 Then
            Set XMLHTTP = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
            Set HTMLDoc_Secondary = New HTMLDocument
            XMLHTTP.Open "GET", .href, False
            XMLHTTP.send
            While XMLHTTP.readyState <> 4: Wend
            HTMLDoc_Secondary.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.responseText
            'Parse HTMLDoc_Secondary
        End If
    End With
Next

Set XMLHTTP = Nothing
Set HTMLDoc_Main = Nothing
Set HTMLDoc_Secondary = Nothing
End Sub
```

Couple notes- 1) I used XMLHTTPRequest instead of IE as it is faster so 2) you are going to need to add 'Microsoft HTML Object Library' and 'Microsoft XML, v6.0' to your references and 3) I can see you are outputting to ranges in your original code- if at all possible this should be avoided. Populate an array and then dump its entire contents out into your target sheet all at once to save time...

Hope this helps,
TheSilkCode

Comment: I believe this will work.  I'll try it when I get to the office.  Thanks!!

Comment: You know, that worked fine in my test sample, but I can't get it working in my actual SharePoint site.  The HTMLDoc_Main.body.innerHTML is too big to fit in a cell and way to big to view in the Immediate Window.  I want to look for this text in the parent URL: 'Upload Questionnaire' and copy/paste the following into cell C2:  href="https://blah_blah/SitePages/blah_blah_blah_TaskListHome.aspx". It should be 'TD class=ms-vb', but it seems like the script can't find that..  Any ideas?